# Change the shape of a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-shape

I am making a party hat using XeLaTeX with TikZ. Clearly for this to work the shape of the `tikzpicture` has to be triangular. How can I accomplish this? And, for the sake of generality, how can you do this for any shape?

**EDIT**: I am using a `standalone` document, so:

```
\documenclass[tikz]{standalone}
% blah blah blah preamble
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% some drawing here
% somehow we have to ensure that all the drawing
% only happens within a specified part
% if anything that comes outide the path is drawn
% it doesn't show up in the picture
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really understand. The bounding box of a `tikzpicture` will always be rectangular, you can't avoid that, but you don't have fill the bounding box. `\fill (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,2) -- cycle;` will draw a triangle.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have edited my question.

Comment: basically, you want to draw a triangle and then fill it with some pattern/picture that ends at the edge of the triangle?

Comment: @riddleculous Yes.

Comment: I have never used it but TikZ supports clipping, see section 15.9 in the pgfmanual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a `\clip` path. If you start your `tikzpicture` with e.g.

```
\clip (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
```

everything that comes later will be clipped away if it is outside that rectangle. You can make any sort of path I think, so my example from the comment above would also work, i.e.

```
\clip (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
```

That said, the final PDF will still be rectangular, that you cannot avoid.

Comment: and if you want to actually draw the shape (i.e. the triangle) with which you are clipping you should use `\draw[clip]` instead of simply `\clip` resp. `\path[clip]`

Comment: Oh! I've used this somewhat often but didn't recognize it would be relevant to this case. Thanks!